# Compare two eloquent requests using Collections

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have a small issue concerning 2 different SQL requests made with Eloquent. 
My first request allows me to have a full list of training session, the second request displays me the training already achieved by users.

So, I have those Eloquent Request (they work separately...)

```
$todo = User::select('formations.typesession_id', 'formation_metier_ua.formation_id', 'formations.codeformation', 'users.id', 'formations.nomformation', 'users.nom', 'users.prenom', 'formations.dureeformation')
        ->distinct()
        ->join('uas', 'users.ua_id', '=', 'uas.id')
        ->join('formation_metier_ua', 'uas.id', '=', 'formation_metier_ua.ua_id')
        ->join('formations', 'formation_metier_ua.formation_id', '=', 'formations.id')
        ->join('typesessions', 'typesessions.id', '=', 'formations.typesession_id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $idUser )
        ->get();

$done = User::select('formations.typesession_id', 'parcoursformations.formation_id', 'formations.codeformation', 'users.id', 'formations.nomformation', 'users.nom', 'users.prenom', 'formations.dureeformation')
        ->distinct()
        ->join('parcoursformations', 'users.id', '=', 'parcoursformations.user_id')
        ->join('formations', 'parcoursformations.formation_id', '=', 'formations.id')
        ->join('typesessions', 'typesessions.id', '=', 'formations.typesession_id')
        ->where('users.id', '=', $idUser )
        ->get();
```

Here is the dump of my requests:

```
(2) [Array(4), Array(3)]
0: Array(4)
    0:{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 1, codeformation: "FR1", id: 3, nomformation: "Hygiène et prévention", …}
    1:{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 6, codeformation: "FR7", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité incendie", …}
    2:{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 7, codeformation: "FR8", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité électrique", …}
    3:{typesession_id: 2, formation_id: 8, codeformation: "GU", id: 3, nomformation: "Gestes d'urgence", …}
1:Array(3)
    0: {typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 6, codeformation: "FR7", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité incendie", …}
    1:{typesession_id: 3, formation_id: 7, codeformation: "FR8", id: 3, nomformation: "Sécurité électrique", …}
    2:{typesession_id: 2, formation_id: 8, codeformation: "GU", id: 3, nomformation: "Gestes d'urgence", …}
```

My issue concerns how I can manage the difference with those 2 collections. Theoretically I should be able to use collections methods such as `diff()`... 
For example, `$todo` contains 4 entries and `$done` contains 1 array ... so I should get the entry "NOT IN" $done

```
$remainingCollection = $todo->diff($done);
$remainingCollection = $remainingCollection->all();
return $remainingCollection;
```

Unfortunately, I have an empty array.

Comment: The easy way out is to create a third query that selects all training sessions that haven't been finished. Could you dump the collections here?

Comment: What sort of collection are you getting? I suspect it's returning an Eloquent collection, and the diff for that does not work the same way as the parent.

Comment: Try `$todo->toBase()->diff($done)`. Though you should probably be doing this with a query.

Comment: in fact it would be better to use collections because i have some other treatment to do on those results such as sums, etc. It would be easier to work on Collection than to have an heavy Eloquent request

Comment: Thanks !! $todo->toBase()->diff($done) works fine ! i'll be able now to manage it !